# reading web.config from class library

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

i have two project
1) class library with no inteface just an api 
2) web application

from web apps i will be calling the class library api

so i have all the web.config settings in the web application but when i debug it always return me null value and here is the code snippit:

```
 public static string readingDB
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;
                result = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["employeeDB"]; //conn string
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";  //???? THROW EXCEPTION???
                }
            }
        }
```

i have also tried, creating a new app.config in the class library project and have the same appsettings there but does not work...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <add name="employeeDB" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;"/>
  </applicationSettings>
  <customErrors mode="On"/>
</configuration>
```

any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
<configuration>  
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="employeeDB" value="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;"/> 
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

or more correctly, since it's a connection string,

```
<configuration>  
  <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="employeeDB" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;"/>  
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

which would be read by `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["employeeDB"]`

Comment: thanks for the correct, but my question still not answered should i have both places the entry? (web.config and app.config)

Comment: @AbuHamzah: You should only have Web.config for ASP.NET Websites.

Comment: +1 You were the only one to actually point out that OP should instead use `<connectionStrings>` for this.

Answer (score 2):

just saw the post and i had same problem but i got a way..
add `System.Web.Configuration` reference to your class library prj
then

`ConnectingString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`

Hope this will help

Comment: `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]` This is worked for me, Thanks @nilantha-ekanayake

Answer (score 1):

Also, the System.Configuration assembly is not automatically added to a class library.

1. Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Click Add > Reference
3. Check System.Configuration in the Assemblies > Framework tab

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is wrong..it should be 'appSettings' not 'applicationSettings'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add name="employeeDB" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <customErrors mode="On"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, but my question still not answered should i have both places the entry? (web.config and app.config)

Comment: Nopes, you just need the entry in web.config of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

appSettings is should be like

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="employeeDB" value="xxxx" />
</appSettings>
```