# How to share dynamic connection string name from asp.net application to class libary (data access layer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a ASP.NET Web application project in which when ever user login , according to User logged in, we get have different connection string name from database and store that in session.

**In Database access Layer**

I have created a class with name ShareSession

```
public class ShareSession
{

    public string ConnectionString1 { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString2 { get; set; }


    public ShareSession()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionString1 = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionStringname1"]);
            ConnectionString2 = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionStringname2"]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard/Login.aspx");
            throw;
        }
    }


}
```

While accessing this object i just create object of this class.

```
 ShareSession objShareSession = new ShareSession();

 var Connection_Database = Convert.ToString(objShareSession.ConnectionString1);



using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connection_Database].ConnectionString)))
{
// Database Logic
}
```

It is performing slow is there any other solution for it.

Scenario:- 
i am setting dynamic connection string name from database everytime when use login it has different region database for normalization if one login from india then his data will be inserted in indian database if he login from USA then his data is inserted into USA database , in this condition how can i send this dynamic name of connection to data access layer

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422186/34092

Comment: What makes you think this is causing the slowness? Have you profiled your application to determine where it is being slow?

Comment: hi mjwills my question is not that simple understand it i am setting dynamic connection string name from database everytime when use login it has different region database for normalization if one login from india then his data will be inserted in indian database if he login from USA then his data is inserted into USA database , in this condition how can i send this dynamic name of connection to data access layer

Comment: hi RB when ever i perform any CRUD operation this class object will be created to get connection string name right there are 60 classes in application which will access this logic.

Comment: my opinion is pass only region name and in data layer user if else of switch for connection string

Comment: I would be very surprised if the cost of creating ShareSession is your issue. The performance cost is far more likely to be related to the cost of creating database connections.

Comment: hi ishan joshi but is there any issue in above code snippet may i know

Comment: Hi mjwills is there any issue in above code snippet may i know which will help me

Comment: When you profiled it, where was the slowness? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: User which are using application are telling is there any issue really in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147075/discussion-between-saineshwar-and-mjwills).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Create a Sealed class for the User and save the connection string there since a sealed class can have only 1 instance(per user) there will not be issue of creating multiple instance to get the same connection string next i would suggest you to pass the connection string as string parameter from BLL to DAL instead of reading it in DAL  (just read the connection string from web config to your constructor class of BLL or in DAL your wish )

Comment: but is it good to pass connection string name as a parameter in every method

Comment: it dosen't matter just make sure you are passing it from BLL and not from Presentation Layer if you are that concern then you can initialize   the connection string in the Constructor function of that particular DAL again its on you i dont think passing connection string from BLL to DAL gonna make a big compromise .